# Popping a Navigation Controller from stack / Creating a dual view

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller, segue

I have implemented a chat system in my app. I want this view to slide in from the right (and cover the whole screen) and then when the user presses a "back button" to slide back to the view they were previously in.

The rest of the app is in a structure that goes:

UINavigationController -> UITabBarController -> UINavigationController -> then whatever view.

The Chat interface is basically just two UIViewControllers (one to see all the conversations and then one for an individual chat). but it's inside a UINavigationController

I wanted to be kind of like the Facebook Online Users page:

[image: Facebook Sliding View]

I've tried to simply push the UINavigationController of the chat app and then push the highest UINavigationController of the main part of the app when the user presses a "back" button, but this always takes me to the first view of the first tab and not the last tab that the user was viewing.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for something like [MMDrawerController](https://github.com/mutualmobile/MMDrawerController).

Comment: Yes, that looks good. However it hasn't been updated in two years and is written in Objective - C. Also my main question is - how to return to the view the user was previously on when switching back to the original navigation controller. I'd still have this problem.